# How can i format this date for NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdate

can anyone help me format this date "Tue, 09 Sep 2014" I've got `"FFF, dd MMM yyyy"` i got this of a NSDate table on some random forum :/ any help is greatly appreciated

Code:
`for (NSString *rawDate in postDateraw){
            NSString *formattedRawDate = [rawDate substringToIndex:[rawDate length]-15];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"FFF, dd MMM yyyy"];
            NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: formattedRawDate];
            dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
            NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];                 NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
        }`

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Looks like it's already formatted. Please explain your problem in more detail. What exactly is the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Provide the code, some explantation what happens, and what you want expected to happen instead would be nice.

Comment: I need to convert a date in the format of `Tue, 09 Sep 2014` into `09-09-14` however i can't figure out how to enter the format for the original date ? the postRawData is an NSMutableArray

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: @CrimsonChris Thank you got it, it was `EEE, d MMM yyyy`:)

Comment: Bookmark it. It's a pain to find and you will definitely use it again.

Answer (score 0):

The character for day-of-week is `E`, not `F`.  Thus:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy"];
```